# Python and a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I am having problems with Python (Django) Framework.  I at first attempted to send a Javascript Array straight to Django except it pulled only the last value.  So I use now `JSON.stringify` which sends my JSON to Python.

At Python it looks like this

```
QueryDict: {u'[{"key:":"interface.dns","value:":192.168.0.1"}]':[u'']}
```

And if I add more values it just adds to the first U.  How can I make this so its a loop.

e.g for each key value in the dictionary display it.  Because it seams the JSON is being stored at position one in the Dictionary.

Any Ideas

Comment: *How can I make this so its a loop.* How can data be a loop? Please show us how you send the data and how you would like to access it on the server side. It seems to me that your main problem is that you don't send a `key-value` pair to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryDict` objects implement the file interface. So you could decode the JSON simply with the standard JSON library:

```
import json
...
parsed_json = json.load(request.POST) # Or GET, depends on what you are using
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Djangos json deserializer:

```
data = request.POST.keys()[0]
for obj in serializers.deserialize("json", data):
    do_something_with(obj)
```

[Read more.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#deserializing-data)

It seems that your json is sent as a key instead of a value in the POST (or GET) request. This can work but for convention it should be in the value part.